# how do I correctly use a list declared in another module

Tags: haskell

I am met with the eoor:

```
> Levels.hs:3:40: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
  |
3 | let screens = ["stage one","stage two"]
  |                                        ^
```

when I try to use a list I declared in a module  called `Levels`. Below is my `main.hs` file:

```
import System.IO
import Levels

main = do  
    putStrLn (head Levels.screens)
```

And below is my Levels.hs

```
module Levels where

let screens = ["stage one","stage two"]
```

Please any idea why I get this error?

Comment: just write `screens = ["stage one","stage two"]` without `let` keyword. Also, if you want to use `Levels.screens` you should use `import qualified Levels`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` is only for declaring variables within some scope – the scope of a function or a monadic block. Basically what it does is, it creates a new top-level environment in which you can then declare variables.

But when writing a source file, you're *already* at the top level, so you don't need to (and in fact, *can't*) use `let`.

Just write it out like

```
module Levels where

screens = ["stage one","stage two"]
```

...preferrably add a type signature also

```
screens :: [String]
```

Where you *could* use `let` is if you needed some helper definitions for implementing that list, like

```
screens = let stage1 = "stage one"
              stage2 = "stage two"
          in [stage1, stage2]
```

or, as it would somewhat more commonly be written,

```
screens = [stage1, stage2]
 where stage1 = "stage one"
       stage2 = "stage two"
```

Note that when using `let` in GHCi, like

```
Prelude> let screens = ["stage one","stage two"]
Prelude> screens
["stage one","stage two"]
```

you're already in a scope, namely an implicit `do` block of the `IO` monad, i.e. this is like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let screens = ["stage one","stage two"]
   putStrLn $ head screens
```